# Language in Settings on Loki Live USB are Russian

Tags: release-loki, language

I just tried elementary OS. I just booted it to try out from a boot USB. I changed the language to German, when I noticed, that the layout was something Russian. So I went a menu back and clicked on stuff like background/Device manager and all these were Russian. is there a fix to this? I'm running the Current Version of elementary OS, Loki.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here, I added Hebrew and got Russian only formats. It was no help deleting all other languages.
Finally succeeded! I had to hit 'set language', then English came out.